# ios - fb sdk - request additional publish permissions

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to get publish permissions in my iOS app. I've been following [Request additional permission Facebook SDK 4 iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999562/request-additional-permission-facebook-sdk-4-ios) but things don't work.

On login, I'm only requesting some read permissions as:

```
// loginButton is a FacebookLoginButton
loginButton.delegate = self
loginButton.loginBehavior = .systemAccount
loginButton.readPermissions = [
  "public_profile",
  "user_friends",
  "email",
]
```

This pings my delegate with a token that works fine. Then later on I want to get publish permissions, so I do:

```
FBSDKLoginManager()
  .logIn(
    withPublishPermissions: ["publish_actions"],
    from: vc,
    handler: { result, error in
    // here:
    // error is nil
    // result.token is nil
    // result.grantedPermissions is nil
    // result.declinedPermissions is nil
    // result.isCanceled is true
  })
```

This shows a prompt that opens in Safari saying "You have already authorized MyApp" and when I tap "OK", this execute the callback with no granted permissions nor tokens.

If I then ping

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=<theAccessTokenIGotAtLogin>
```

I get

```
{ data: 
   [ { permission: 'user_friends', status: 'granted' },
     { permission: 'email', status: 'granted' },
     { permission: 'public_profile', status: 'granted' } ] }
```

ie I didn't get the publish permissions and never had them. I tried several times, removing the app from fb settings, logging in and out...

Comment: Same issue here. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I also have the same issue. Does anyone know a solution for this?