# How to post to user's facebook feed

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdk

I need to post to user's facebook feed.

Based on several other SO questions I came up with the following posting request:

```
let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: ["message" : "Hello world"], accessToken: accessToken, httpMethod: .POST, apiVersion: GraphAPIVersion.defaultVersion)
request.start({ (response, requestResult) in

    switch requestResult {
    case .failed(let error):
        print("error in graph request:", error)

    case .success(let graphResponse):
        if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
            print(responseDictionary)
        }
    }
})
```

This fails due to

```
error =         {
    code = 200;
    "fbtrace_id" = GMp2cebddNb;
    message = "(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission";
    type = OAuthException;
};
```

Based on the message, the problem seemed to be an easy to solve - all I need is to get either `publish_actions`, or `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions. Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999562/request-additional-permission-facebook-sdk-4-ios), this seemed easy and I ended up in wrapping the code for posting with this:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
loginManager.logIn([PublishPermission.custom("publish_actions")], viewController: self) { (result) in

    print(">> \(AccessToken.current?.grantedPermissions)")

    switch result {

    case .cancelled:
        print(">>>> Cancelled")

    case .failed(let error):
        print(">>>> Error: \(error)" )

    case .success(grantedPermissions: _, declinedPermissions: _, token: let accessToken):
        print(">>>> Logged in!")
        let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: ["message" : post], accessToken: accessToken, httpMethod: .POST, apiVersion: GraphAPIVersion.defaultVersion)
        request.start({ (response, requestResult) in

            switch requestResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print("error in graph request:", error)
                break
            case .success(let graphResponse):
                if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                    print(responseDictionary)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now the "funny" part is, that then the facebook SDK shows a page telling me that I previously logged in to my app using Facebook and asks me if I would like to continue. When I press Continue, the `SafariViewController` dismisses and the `.cancelled` branch gets executed. What is going on here? I haven't cancelled, nor have I been asked to grant permissions to publish anything on my feed.

P.S.: I tried logging out first (`loginManager.logOut()` and/or `AccessToken.current = nil`), in that case the `.success` branch executes but again with the same error `"(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission"`.

The `AccessToken.current.grantedPermissions` in that case contains:

```
Set([FacebookCore.Permission(name: "user_friends"),
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "publish_pages"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "user_location"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "email"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "user_likes"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "pages_show_list"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "manage_pages"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "user_photos"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "public_profile"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "user_posts"), 
    FacebookCore.Permission(name: "user_birthday")])
```

So no `publish_actions` permission! Why does the login go through successfully while not granting me the permission that I ask for? Moreover, I obviously have `"manage_pages"` and `"publish_pages"`, so why is that not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-24-2018

> The publish_actions permission has been removed.

Since they do not mention any alternative, there is no way to post to the user feed anymore.

Comment: not a good news, but at least this seems to be giving me the explanation of what is going on

Comment: Additionally, Facebook removed the ability to publish into a User profile, and they recommend using Sharing Buttons...

Comment: well, that is exactly what publish_actions was about, to publish on a user profile ;)