# Access token behaving differently now than before July - 2- 2018

Tags: facebook-graph-api, token

I have a friend that runs a small nonprofit which helps find placement for dogs that have been brought to animal shelters.  This organization has a Facebook page that allows volunteers coordinate and donate funds for these animals.

I had created an application that uploaded posts, downloaded and edited posts, and downloaded comments.

It did so using standard HTTP protocols with a Facebook Access Token.  The token was obtained by going out to the graph explorer and copying it to the application.

This worked perfectly well until July – 2, when the two thousand or so post that were already uploaded and visible just disappeared.  Oddly, it is now possible to use the tokens from graph explorer again, but they are giving erratic results and all the posts prior to July-2 are still missing.

Does anyone understand this behavior? And if so does anyone have any suggestions on how I could fix it?

Thank you,
Demetrius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Facebook seems to have removed the ability to post from outside of their own apps.

See [How to post to user's facebook feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172571/how-to-post-to-users-facebook-feed)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Yes that was the impression that I got, but I was surprised how little discussion there was on the subject.